# Gradient function on R and Python

Tags: python, r, output

I was testing a code in R and then I wanted to use a similar code in Python. I have this potential:`Z = 1/sqrt(Y^2+X^2+2*d*X+d^2)`. I tried to plot it with R using the pracma package like this:

```
require(pracma)

range = seq(-15,15,by=1)
mesh = meshgrid(range,range)

X = mesh$X
Y = mesh$Y    
d = 5

# Now I define the potential:
Z = 1/sqrt(Y^2+X^2+2*d*X+d^2)
contour(range,range,t(Z),col="black",xlab="x",ylab="y")

# Now the gradient:
grX = gradient(Z,range,range)$X
grY = gradient(Z,range,range)$Y

# I wanted the vectors to be normalized so I did this:
grXN = grX/sqrt(grX^2+grY^2)
grYN = grY/sqrt(grX^2+grY^2)

# Finally I draw the vector field:
quiver(X,Y,grXN,grYN,scale=0.5,col="black")
```

When I run this code I get this:
[Quiver in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ouW.png)
Which is more or less what I wanted, except it is a bit ugly.

Then I made this code in Python like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.arange(-15,15,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(rng,rng)
d = 5

# Now I define the potential:
Z = 1/np.sqrt(Y**2+X**2+2*d*X+d**2)

# Now the gradient:
grX,grY = np.gradient(Z)

# Since I want the vectors normalized I did this:
grXN = grX/np.sqrt(grX**2+grY**2)
grYN = grY/np.sqrt(grX**2+grY**2)

# In this case I made a different contour:
contor = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,50)
cbar = plt.colorbar(contor)

# Finally the arrows:
Q = plt.quiver(X,Y,grXN,grYN,color="w",scale=30)
```

When I run this code I get this:
[Quiver in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRzzC.png)
Which is cute, but totally different from the result obtained from R. Why?

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python arrows are simply twisted through 90° relative to your R arrows.  The reason is the difference in convention between `numpy` and `matplotlib` when it comes to the order of the dimensions "X" and "Y".   For reasons of (debatable) intuitiveness, `matplotlib` functions—like those of its mad uncle, Matlab—typically ask for X, then Y, in that order. Likewise, taking its inspiration from Matlab's well-worn `meshgrid` function, `numpy.meshgrid` also adopts that convention, in that its `indexing` argument defaults to `'xy'`. But I believe `numpy.gradient` must be following the more usual `numpy`-esque assumption of `'ij'` indexing (and when visualizing arrays, Y is usually the row-to-row `'i'` dimension, which in `numpy` arrays is dimension 0, so then X is usually the column-to-column `'j'` dimension, dimension 1).  Therefore, you should actually be saying:

```
grY,grX = np.gradient(Z)
```

instead of

```
grX,grY = np.gradient(Z)
```

Comment: Jajajaja! Mad uncle! Thank you very much!!! Good to know that, I really did not think that was the problem... It works perfectly now!